# Errors : ora-00604&ora-1578 &ora-01110

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

I get `ora-00604` & `ora-1578` & `ora-01110`, any one have solution ????

[image]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

That doesn't sound good.

```
ORA-01578: ORACLE data block corrupted (file # string, block # string)

Cause : The data block indicated was corrupted, mostly due to software errors.

Action: Try to restore the segment containing the block indicated. 
        This may involve dropping the segment and recreating it. 
        If there is a trace file, report the errors in it to your ORACLE representative.
```

`system02` database file is corrupted; there's a possibility that hard disk *crashed* and you should check it for errors. As it is the database server, I presume that it would be safer if you replaced it (instead of just fixed it, because - when one data block gets corrupted, there's a good chance that it'll happen again (according to Murphy's law, at least)).

Furthermore, it means that you'll have to restore the database. I hope you have backup (the one you got BEFORE corruption happened).